# How to count agents in anylogic?

Tags: agent, anylogic

I want to count an agent population (number of agents) from another agent, and if needed remove or add them.

I have used this code:

```
get_Main().Retailer.Inventory.item()
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you count a collection as "myCollection.size()". If you want to count the numbers of AgentB agents from another agent, say AgentA, you need to access the collection of AgentBs correctly. It depends on where it sits. If both AgentA and AgentB collections sit in the Main, it would be code in AgentA as:

```
get_Main().AgentB.size()
```

Hope that helps.